# phpbrew not connecting to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have set up phpbrew, including installing all [requirements](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/wiki/Requirement) and have successfully compiled php-5.6.11 using the following command:

```
sudo phpbrew --debug install php-5.6.11 +default+mysql+pdo+debug +apxs2 -- --with-mysql-sock=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.soc
```

I can switch between php versions using the phpbrewswitch script below, which I found in [this comment](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/issues/226#issuecomment-170124212):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
VERSION=$1

SOFILE=/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp$VERSION.so
CONFFILE=/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.load

source ~/.phpbrew/bashrc

if [ -f $SOFILE ]; then
    phpbrew switch $VERSION
    phpbrew list

    FILECONTENTS="LoadModule php5_module $SOFILE"
    echo $FILECONTENTS > $CONFFILE

    echo "Updated $CONFFILE"
    sudo service apache2 restart

else
    echo $VERSION "is not configured for apache"
    phpbrew list 
fi
```

This script simply uses phpbrew to switch php versions and tells apache to use the .so file for the requested version, then reboots apache. (all in one commmand which makes it easy to switch back & forth yay!)

However switching between my local php 5.6.11 installation and the phpbrew 5.6.11 install causes mysql to stop connecting. phpinfo runs fine on both versions and displays relevant info, just FYI. What am I missing? Is there something in php.ini to make mysql work? Is it a parameter I'm missing when compiling with phpbrew?  Any advice is appreciated, I would really like to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. It turns out that the mysql host variable in my php scripts was set to "localhost". Explicitly setting it to "127.0.0.1" did the trick. Not sure why localhost wasn't resolving but whatevs. IT WORKS! XD

Answer (score 2):

Check the mysql socket path in the config file, it may differ from other version php.